# No module named 'sklearn' even though it is installed and seen in pip list

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I have installed python 3.10 and pip by itself (without conda or anything else) on Windows 11 64 bit.

I have a working Jupyter notebook setup, but can't get sklearn to work.

When I run the following command inside of the jupyter notebook I get:

```
! pip list

Package            Version
------------------ ---------
certifi            2022.6.15
charset-normalizer 2.1.1
distlib            0.3.6
filelock           3.8.0
idna               3.3
joblib             1.2.0
numpy              1.23.3
pip                22.2.2
platformdirs       2.5.2
requests           2.28.1
scikit-learn       1.0.2
scipy              1.9.1
setuptools         58.1.0
sklearn            0.0
threadpoolctl      3.1.0
urllib3            1.26.12
virtualenv         20.16.3
```

But in the next cell I run this code, and get the following error

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-21e1a2676f4e> in <module>
      3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      4 
----> 5 from sklearn import tree
      6 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
```

I have tried uninstalling the module, reinstalling it. Restarting the computer, restarting the notebook, restarting the kernel. Tried installing it throguh commandline, PowerShell and through Jupyter notebook.

Comment: 1/ Which (pip) installation command did you use? 2/ How did you start the Jupyter notebook?

Comment: Also, are you using virtual environments? It's quite likely that the kernel you're using in Jupyter is not connected to the environment you installed into.

Comment: I have tried a few different install commands. `pip install scikit-learn` and `pip install -U scikit-learn` (-U might have been before install). And don't use virtual environments. I start up jupyter notebook by the command `jupyter notebook`

Comment: Your Pip installations probably doesn't match your Python installation. Try `python -m pip install scikit-learn` instead. That should guarantee Pip matching your Python executable. Similar for starting a notebook: `python -m jupyter notebook`. Note that a virtual environment should guarantee that Python, Pip and JuPyteR match, but outside this solutions should also work nicely.

Comment: When I do that I get that scikit-learn is already installed. But the second command gives me "No module named jupyter", which makes sense if you are right. But how can I install jupyter in a way that makes everything work then?